# Inexplicable 403 Error w/ Python Get Request

Tags: python-requests

I'm trying to do a simple get request but no matter how I'm configuring the headers I keep getting a 403 response. The page loads fine in a browser. No login is required and there are no tracked cookies either. The link I'm trying to get a response from is below, followed by my simple code.

https://i7.sportsdatabase.com/nba/query.json?sdql=50+%3C+Kobe+Bryant%3Apoints+and+site%3Daway&sport=nba

```
url = 'https://i7.sportsdatabase.com/nba/query.json?sdql=50+%3C+Kobe+Bryant%3Apoints+and+site%3Daway&sport=nba'

headers = {
    'Host': 'i7.sportsdatabase.com',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.131 Safari/537.36',
}

r = requests.get(url, headers)
```

I'm not seeing any other headers that need adding to the request. The full, in browser, request headers are below:

```
Host: i7.sportsdatabase.com
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
sec-ch-ua: "Chromium";v="92", " Not A;Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="92"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
DNT: 1
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.131 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
Sec-Fetch-Site: none
Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
Sec-Fetch-User: ?1
Sec-Fetch-Dest: document
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en,en-US;q=0.9,it;q=0.8,es;q=0.7
If-None-Match: "be833f0fb26eb81487fc09e05c85ac8c8646fc7b"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

1. Make your URL a string
2. Add the accepts

This works:

```
url = 'https://i7.sportsdatabase.com/nba/query.json?sdql=50+%3C+Kobe+Bryant%3Apoints+and+site%3Daway&sport=nba'

headers = {
    'Host': 'i7.sportsdatabase.com',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.131 Safari/537.36',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
}

r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try using `.Session()`

```
import requests

s = requests.Session()
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.159 Mobile Safari/537.36',
}

s.get('https://i7.sportsdatabase.com/nba/trends', headers=headers)

url = 'https://i7.sportsdatabase.com/nba/query.json?sdql=50+%3C+Kobe+Bryant%3Apoints+and+site%3Daway&sport=nba'
r = s.get(url, headers=headers)

print(r)
```

**Output:**

```
print(r)
<Response [200]>
```